# Changing the "size" or "color" label in Plotly

Tags: plotly, legend, label

For the chart used in the example here:

https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/#adding-color-and-size-mapping

I'm wondering, is it possible to modify the label of the color scale from "carat" to something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is just the name of the column in their dataset that they are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it by using the `title` property under, `marker` -> colorbar.

The details of the property is as follows:

> **title (string)**
>   Sets the title of the color bar.

Follow the [link](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-marker-colorbar-title) to go to the plotly r documentation.

Finally here is the code, please let me know if this fixes your issue!

```
library(plotly)

d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]

p <- plot_ly(
  d, x = ~carat, y = ~price,mode = 'scatter', 
  marker = list(showscale = TRUE, colorbar = list(title = "sometitle")),
  text = ~paste("Price: ", price, '$<br>Cut:', cut),
  color = ~carat, size = ~carat
)

chart_link = api_create(p, filename="scatter-hovertext")
chart_link
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, it was the marker function I was looking for!